# Problem with Density Plot and Normal Density Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am asked to plot the density of the residuals of my dataset against the density of a normal distribution.

When I do this with `ggplot2`, it shows me my residual density plot, but not the normal distribution. Additionally, two error messages occur:

> ```
> Removed 134 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
> Removed 403 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
> ```

Could somebody explain me why the normal plot is not shown?

Please find my code below:

```
p1 <-  ggplot(steak_eaters)+ geom_density(aes(x= resid))

p1 <- p1 + stat_function(fun =dnorm, n=403, args= list(mean= mean(steak_eaters$resid), sd = sd(steak_eaters$resid)), color= "red") + theme_stata() 


plot(p1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to your `steak_eaters` dataset, but here is an example with the `geom_function` function and a built-in dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=depth)) +
  geom_density(color="blue") +
  geom_function(fun=function(x) 
                dnorm(x, 
                      mean=mean(diamonds$depth),
                      sd=sd(diamonds$depth)),
                      color="red")
```

[image]

The messages you copy seem like *warning* messages rather than *error* messages. You probably have missing observations or infinite values in the dataset, which get dropped by the `ggplot2` plotting mechanism.